# SimpleJdbcCall NullPointerException on Firebird DB

Tags: sql, spring, stored-procedures, jdbc, firebird

I have a problem with calling a stored procedure on Firebird. My procedure has one parameter (UID) and returns one value ID.

```
...
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
// sp declaration
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
      .withProcedureName("SP_NEWRECORD").declareParameters(
       new SqlParameter("UID", Types.INTEGER),
       new SqlOutParameter("NEWID", Types.INTEGER));
Map<String, Object> in = new HashMap<String, Object>();
in.put("UID", uid);
in.put("NEWID", 0);

try {
Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in); //here throws Exception
    last_inserted = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(out.get("NEWID")));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    System.out.println("createRecord result id=" + last_inserted);
}
// return id of inserted record
return last_inserted;
```

Catalina out

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractResultSet.getRow(AbstractResultSet.java:1307)
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractCallableStatement.assertHasData(AbstractCallableStatement.java:998)
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractCallableStatement.getObject(AbstractCallableStatement.java:773)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyCallableStatement.getObject(NewProxyCallableStatement.java:675)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.extractOutputParameters(JdbcTemplate.java:1168)
```

code of SP is very simple, creates new record in table and returns ID of inserted record

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_NEWRECORD (UID integer)
RETURNS (NEWID integer)
AS
declare variable ID integer;
begin
  ID=GEN_ID(gen_myrecords_id,1);
  insert into myrecords (id,uid)
  values (:id,:uid);
  newid=ID;
end
```

Comment: Which Jaybird version are you using?

Comment: firebird version is 2.5, jaybird version is 2.1.6

Comment: Could you try with [Jaybird 2.2.4](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/)?

Comment: nothing changed. But i don't understand , why System.out.println(jdbcCall.getCallString()); returns {call SP_NEWRECORD(?,?)} ,  But Firebird uses "EXECUTE PROCEDURE" statement not "call"

Comment: `{call ...}` is the JDBC escape for stored procedures, all drivers are required to support this. Jaybird translates this to the Firebird specific syntax. However I am wondering if the problem isn't caused by the fact that you register the return value as an OUT parameter. I'd need to check that and get back to you. You might want to try to drop the declaration of the OUT parameter, and use `withReturnValue()` instead. Not sure if this will work though.

Comment: I have changed this    new SqlParameter("UID", Types.VARCHAR)     to SqlParameter("UID", Types.INTEGER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate problem is that currently Jaybird makes no clear distinction between `OUT` parameters (which Firebird technically doesn't have), the (single row) return values of an executable procedure, and the (multiple row) result set of a selectable stored procedure. The problem you are experiencing is (at least partially) related to [JDBC-229](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-229) (and a general review of the `CallableStatement` implementation that is planned for Jaybird 3.0).

This leads to a situation where the result set backing the single row is read twice, once as a `ResultSet` and once through the getters on `CallableStatement`, however as the backing result set has been closed, this causes a `NullPointerException` when the `OUT` parameter is retrieved.

There are two potential workarounds:

1. Disable results processing on the `JdbcTemplate`:

   ```
   JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
   jdbcTemplate.setSkipResultsProcessing(true);
   ```
2. Do not declare the `OUT` parameter, and process the result set that is returned in the `out` map (which contains a `List` with a `Map` for the result set):

   ```
   last_inserted = (int) ((List<Map>) out.get("#result-set-1")).get(0).get("NEWID");
   ```

Note that the cast from `Object` to `int` assumes Java 7 or higher.

I have reported this specific problem as [JDBC-350](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-350) and I will try to fix this in the next Jaybird release (2.2.6).

Comment: So, what's your suggestion prior to Jaybird 3.0? Should we (e.g. when adding SP support to [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org)) simply generate PSQL to fetch those "`OUT`" parameters, instead of using the JDBC escape syntax?

Comment: @LukasEder The simplest is to treat everything as if it is selectable (produces a `ResultSet`), this should work in all existing Jaybird versions. This even works when using JDBC escape syntax: just specify the `IN` parameters only. Preserving this compatibility might give me some headaches for Jaybird 3 though ;)

Comment: Too late. It's implemented as suggested by you, now :)

Comment: @LukasEder I might just add a restriction that you can't use `ResultSet`-like and `OUT` at the same time.

Comment: Yep. That isn't supported in SQL Server either, if you have table-valued-functions I believe. But you can have `OUT` parameters and random (undeclared) result sets in SQL Server. Anyway, if in doubt, I believe that HSQLDB is pretty standards-compliant with respect to routines...